# AngularJS won't display (parse) data that is delivered with $http.get in Laravel5

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I have a **simple SPA application** ,just to s**how some data from the database in Laravel 5** ,and for the **front-end** I'm using **AngularJS** . My angular files are all in **public** folder .

When i go to **localhost** instead of a list of users I get literally this

```
{{ user1.name }} , {{ user1.email }}
{{ user1.phone_number }}
```

Here are my files :

**route.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function(){
    Route::resource('jokes', 'User1Controller');
});
```

**PageController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User1 ;
use App\Http\Requests;

class PageController extends Controller
{

        public function index()
    {
        return view('index'); 
    }
}
```

**User1Controller.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Response;
use App\User1 ;

class User1Controller extends Controller
{
        public function index() {
        return response()->json( User1::get() );
    }


    public function store(Request $request) {
        User1::create([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'phone_number' => $request->input('phone_number')
        ]);
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }

}
```

**User1.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User1 extends Model
{
        protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'phone_number'
    ];
}
```

**resources/views/index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=eng>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Welcome </title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- load bootstrap via cdn -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- load fontawesome -->
  <style>
    body    { padding-top:30px; }
/*    form    { padding-bottom:20px; }
*/  </style>

  <!-- JS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script> <!-- load our application -->
    <script src="js/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script> <!-- load our controller -->
    <script src="js/services/commentServices.js"></script> <!-- load our service -->
</head>
<body   class="container" ng-app="user1App" ng-controller="mainController">

  <div class="user1"  ng-repeat="user1 in user1s">
    <h3> <small>{{ user1.name }} , {{ user1.email }}</small></h3>
    <p>{{ user1.phone_number }}</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**public/js/app.js**

```
angular.module('user1App', [
  'controllers',
  'services'
]);

angular.module('controllers', []);
angular.module('services', []);
```

**public/js/controllers/mainCtrls.js**

```
var Controller = angular.module('controllers');

Controller.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, User1, $sce) {
  // get all the comments first and bind it to the $scope.user1s object
  User1.get()
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.user1s = data;
    });
});
```

**public/js/services/user1Services.js**

```
var Service = angular.module('services');

Service.factory('User1', function($http) {

  return {
    get : function() {
      return $http.get('api/v1/jokes');
    }

  };

});
```

**I have seedes the database and on the localhost/api/v1/joke there are some users because i checked it with Postman**
[image]

Comment: can you share the output of console.log($scope.user1s)

Comment: Do you get an error in your console?

Comment: Hm ,I'm not watching the console ,because I run the laravel project in docker container http://www.spiralout.eu/2015/12/dockervel-laravel-development.html ,so I don't have to run .... php artisan serve .... i only hit dpermit . But when I run dgulp watch i don't get anyithing

Comment: @NagaSaiA if i put it in User1.get...{.. console.log($scope.user1s); } I don't get anything in console ,i don't run anything to track the app in console,should I?

Comment: try alert(JSON.stringify($scope.user1s));

Comment: @NagaSaiA    User1.get()
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.user1s = data;
      alert(JSON.stringify($scope.user1s));
    });                                          and when I go to localhost the same happends,no alert

Comment: it seems like data is not available in the $scope.user1s

Comment: @NagaSaiA yyou think the .get fails ?

Comment: yes @moonlight... can you check with alerts with in controller and within Users1.get success function ..just to chec whether it is failing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116888/discussion-between-naga-sai-a-and-moonlight).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result , use below option

```
angular.module('user1App', []);

angular.module('user1App').controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, User1, $sce) { 

$http.get('api/v1/jokes').success(function(data) { 

$scope.user1s = data; 

}); 


}
```