# Can't load AngularJs files from PUBLIC folder in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

**I'm having troubles referencing my angularJS files in Laravel's "public" folder. My                            public folder structure looks like this:**:

```
public

   -css

   -js

      -services

      -controllers

      -app.js
```

**I have my "index.php" file inside the "app/views" folder**.**When i go to the home page of my application http://localhost, the browser brings me to the index.php file as expected.**

**Inside my "index.php" file, i want to reference my javascript files under the "public/js" and I get "GET http://localhost/js/app.js 404 (Not Found)" - in the browser console meaning that those files can't be found. These are some of the options i have tried to include them in the "index.php" file:**

```
 1.   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

and

EDIT:

```
 <script src="<?php echo asset('/js/app.js'); ?>">
<script src="<?= url('js/app.js') ?>">
```

and

1. I have tried to move the js/app.js to folders resources  or resources/views .
2. I have tried to move just the app.js to resources/views

All these options don't find the files under the "public" folder.
**I don't use BLADE**

My files look like :

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=eng>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Welcome </title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- load bootstrap via cdn -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- load fontawesome -->
  <style>
    body    { padding-top:30px; }
/*    form    { padding-bottom:20px; }
*/  </style>

  <!-- JS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js">
    </script> <!-- load our application --><!-- load our application -->
</head>


<body   class="container" ng-app="user1App" ng-controller="mainController">

  <div class="user1"  ng-repeat="user1 in user1s">
    <h3> <small>{{ user1.name }} , {{ user1.email }}</small></h3>
    <p>{{ user1.phone_number }}</p>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('user1App', [
]);

angular.module('user1App').controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, User1, $sce) {

$http.get('api/v1/jokes').success(function(data) { 

$scope.user1s = data; 

});
}
```

**My config/view.php  looks like** :

```
'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('resources/views')),
],
```

For more information  about my code look here [AngularJS won't display (parse) data that is delivered with $http.get in Laravel5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284736/angularjs-wont-display-parse-data-that-is-delivered-with-http-get-in-laravel)

**ERROR in console :**

```
GET http://localhost/js/app.js 404 (Not Found)
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

**Please help ,I'm realy not seeing the problem and can't google it anywhere.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Leave your files at `public/js` and retrieve it like:

```
<script src="<?= url('js/app.js') ?>">
```

You mentioned doing `<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}">`, but it should contain `js/app.js` instead of `/js/app.js` and obviously replace `{{ }}` with php tags if you are not using blade.

Comment: Yes you are right about {{ }} .. But I have tried you suggestion ,but the same is happening. It onlz works if I put all .js files inside script in index.php.

Comment: Every time i'm getiing this  GET http://localhost/js/app.js 404 (Not Found) . Maybe the public dir. is not the one where it is searching for.

Comment: Can you load the js if viewing directly in the browser?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The only way I can load .js is to put <script>angularjs code</script> in index.php

Comment: Type the js location in the address bar of the browser and see what happens.

Comment: I tried this 
localhost/public/js/app.js  and get NotFoundHttpException

Comment: Have you modified your `.htaccess` in any way after installing `laravel`?

Comment: No, I will put it above in question so you can take a look.

Comment: I run laravel in docker container , but I have installed node modules. Mazbe I should add some permissions to public directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use blade

```
  <script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}">
```

Its will not work, because, '{{' is blade's feature, so what you can do is:

```
  <script src="<?php echo asset('/js/app.js'); ?>">
```

Comment: Ok I have edited the question. Tried   <script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"> 
but still getting GET http://localhost/js/app.js 404 (Not Found) .