# POST request works in browser but NOT in Postman. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, post, postman

**I'm writing Laravel -AngularJS app ,and a post method that I'm calling is passing in browser the data gets updated and in Postman I get the error**

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null**

The databse is also updated ,-I checked it with

> artisan tinker
>   .

My code can be found here [AngularJS won't display (parse) data that is delivered with $http.get in Laravel5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284736/angularjs-wont-display-parse-data-that-is-delivered-with-http-get-in-laravel) ,with index.php that is changed like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=eng>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Welcome </title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- load bootstrap via cdn -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- load fontawesome -->
  <style>
    body    { padding-top:30px; }
/*    form    { padding-bottom:20px; }
*/  </style>

  <!-- JS -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script >


                angular.module('user1App', [
          ]);

          angular.module('user1App').controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {

          $scope.user1Data = {};

          $http.get('api/v1/jokes').success(function(data) { 

          $scope.user1s = data; 

          });

          $scope.submitUser1 = function() {
              //$scope.loading = true;

              // save the comment. pass in comment data from the form
        $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/v1/jokes',
        type: 'JSON',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: JSON.stringify($scope.user1Data)
        }).success(function(User1data) { 
          $scope.user1Data = {};
                 });

            };

          });

    </script>
</head>



<body   class="container" ng-app="user1App" ng-controller="mainController">



  <form name="newForm" ng-submit="submitUser1()"> <!-- ng-submit will disable the default form action and use our function -->

    <!-- NAME -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="name" ng-model="user1Data.name" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>

    <!-- COMMENT TEXT -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" ng-model="user1Data.email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control input-lg" name="phon_number" ng-model="user1Data.phone_number" placeholder="Phone_number" required>
    </div>

    <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
    <div class="form-group text-right"> 
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Register</button>
    </div>
  </form>



  <div class="user1"  ng-repeat="user1 in user1s">
    <h3> <small>{{ user1.name }} , {{ user1.email }}</small></h3>
    <p>{{ user1.phone_number }}</p>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you certain that you changed the method in Postman to be a "POST" instead of a "GET"?

Comment: It's strange cause I can't see the Body section either.

Comment: That seems to indicate that you did not change the dropdown in Postman to "POST".

Comment: But that's not the case , I could printscreen it.

Comment: Maybe missing header : `Content-Type: application/json`, `Accept: application/json` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this.

I have changed method  USer1Controller.php from this:

```
   public function store(Request $request) {
        User1::create([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'phone_number' => $request->input('phone_number')
        ]);
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }
```

to that :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{       
        $this->validate($request , [
            'name' =>'required' ,
            'email' =>'required' ,
            'phone_number' =>'required' ,   
            ]);

        $user= new User1;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email =  $request->email;
        $user->phone_number =  $request->phone_number;
        $user->save();

    return response()->json(['success' => true]);

}
```